# How can I create custom org-mode templates?

Tags: org-mode, template

I use `org-mode` to maintain my personal site. Whenever I create a new `.org` file in my website, I find myself retyping the following

```
#+TITLE: 
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil whn:nil toc:nil nav:nil
#+HTML_HEAD:
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:
```

Is it possible to bind this template to a keystroke?

Comment: Are you willing to use Yasnippet?

Comment: I'm willing to learn anything that works!

Comment: I use [autoinsert](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) mode for this purpose. No keystrokes to learn.

Comment: See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/is-it-possible-to-add-templates-other-than-begin-end-to-org-structure-temp) discussion for latest org-mode template usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the templating system of org-mode. If you insert the following lines at the end of your `init.el` file:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
             '("P" "#+TITLE:\n#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil whn:nil toc:nil nav:nil\n#+HTML_HEAD:\n#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:\n\n? "))
```

After you restart emacs or source your `init.el` file, you only have to type `<P` at the beginning of your org-mode file, then the `<TAB>` key and this will automatically integrate the desired code.

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-templates.html for the documentation of the template mechanism.

Comment: AFAIU, this is obsolete. Starting with 9.2, `tempo-define-template` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/how-to-use-Org-Babel-for-R.html) example wherein the author suggests this `define-skeleton`:

```
(define-skeleton org-skeleton
  "In-buffer settings info for a emacs-org file."
  "Title: "
  "#+TITLE:" str " \n"
  "#+AUTHOR: Your Name\n"
  "#+email: your-email@server.com\n"
  "#+INFOJS_OPT: \n"
  "#+BABEL: :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes \n"
  "-----"
 )
(global-set-key [C-S-f4] 'org-skeleton)
```

Customize to please. But like so many things in the Emacs world, I don't know if this is "best practice."

There is also `autoinsert` which will insert lines whenever you create a new file. Here's what I have in my init:

```
(use-package autoinsert
  :ensure t
  :init
  ;; Don't want to be prompted before insertion:
  (setq auto-insert-query nil)

  (setq auto-insert-directory (locate-user-emacs-file "templates"))
  (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
  (auto-insert-mode 1)

  :config
  (define-auto-insert "\\.org?$" "default-org.org"))
```

Note the last line `(define-auto-insert "\\.org?$" "default-org.org")` So the file `default-org.org` (in my `.emacs.d` directory) contains my customized in-buffer settings, which will be automatically inserted at the top whenever I create a file with an `org` ending.

Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to plant variables and expanding things in this template, as is supposedly possible. (See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54278/using-auto-insert-and-yasnippet-to-insert-variables-into-template) cry for help.)