# Is it possible to add templates other than #+BEGIN_ #+END_ to org-structure-template-alist?

Tags: org-mode

I've noticed that org-structure-template-alist changed (I'm using org-mode version 9.2) to automatically expand to `#+BEGIN_<some block tag> #+END_<some block tag>`. I wonder if it's possible to add different kind of templates. For instance a `:PROPERTIES:<some properties>:END:` template.

Is it possible or should I turn to another package like yasnippets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE:

Haven't noticed that [Org Mode 9.2](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html#org1b5e967) changed the mechanism of template expansion,
where `org-structure-template-alist` is only for blocks defined by `"#+BEGIN_"` and `"#+END_"`.
And entry like `("p" ":PROPERTIES:?:END:")` is no longer accepted.

As mentioned in the above link, other "complex" template can be defined by function `tempo-define-template` ,
and org-tempo must be loaded(`(require 'org-tempo)`). Actually the entries of `org-structure-template-alist`
are converted to `org-tempo-tags` via `tempo-define-template` by `org-tempo`, and `org-tempo-tags` defaults to:

```
(("<i" . tempo-template-org-index)
 ("<A" . tempo-template-org-ascii)
 ("<H" . tempo-template-org-html)
 ("<L" . tempo-template-org-latex)
 ("<v" . tempo-template-org-verse)
 ("<s" . tempo-template-org-src)
 ("<q" . tempo-template-org-quote)
 ("<l" . tempo-template-org-export-latex)
 ("<h" . tempo-template-org-export-html)
 ("<E" . tempo-template-org-export)
 ("<e" . tempo-template-org-example)
 ("<C" . tempo-template-org-comment)
 ("<c" . tempo-template-org-center)
 ("<a" . tempo-template-org-export-ascii)
 ("<I" . tempo-template-org-include))
```

For your case, you can define a template by:

```
(tempo-define-template "my-property"
               '(":PROPERTIES:" p ":END:" >)
               "<p"
               "Insert a property tempate")
```

---

*Below answer only works for Org mode version prior to 9.2*

Yes, you could add an entry to it like this:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("p" ":PROPERTIES:?:END:"))
```

Then in org file, you type `<p` and `TAB`, it will expand to property and
leave the point at the position of `?`.

And you can find more details in the documentation of the variable by typing `C-h v org-structure-template-alist RET`.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks. Btw, Is the `>` symbol on the `tempo-define-template` a typo? If not.... What is the role of it in the definition?

Comment: Glad it helps:) Not a typo, it means the line would be indented, `tempo-define-template` is built-in defun, see the [docstring](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/tempo.el#L220) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The frequency at which they introduce incompatible changes in the customization of org-mode is really a pity.

The following code gives you the old structure templates of org-mode prior to version 9.2 back. The function `org-complete-expand-structure-template` is a pure copy from version 9.1 and `org-try-structure-completion` is a slightly modified version of that one of 9.1. (I added a type-check there.)

After installing that code you can just use your old template
`(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("p" ":PROPERTIES:?:END:"))`
again.

```el
(defvar org-structure-template-alist)

(defun org+-avoid-old-structure-templates (fun &rest args)
  "Call FUN with ARGS with modified `org-structure-template-alist'.
Use a copy of `org-structure-template-alist' with all
old structure templates removed."
  (let ((org-structure-template-alist
     (cl-remove-if
      (lambda (template)
        (null (stringp (cdr template))))
      org-structure-template-alist)))
    (apply fun args)))

(eval-after-load "org"
  '(when (version<= "9.2" (org-version))
     (defun org-try-structure-completion ()
       "Try to complete a structure template before point.
This looks for strings like \"<e\" on an otherwise empty line and
expands them."
       (let ((l (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point)))
         a)
     (when (and (looking-at "[ \t]*$")
            (string-match "^[ \t]*<\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)$" l)
            (setq a (assoc (match-string 1 l) org-structure-template-alist))
            (null (stringp (cdr a))))
       (org-complete-expand-structure-template (+ -1 (point-at-bol)
                              (match-beginning 1)) a)
       t)))

     (defun org-complete-expand-structure-template (start cell)
       "Expand a structure template."
       (let ((rpl (nth 1 cell))
         (ind ""))
     (delete-region start (point))
     (when (string-match "\\`[ \t]*#\\+" rpl)
       (cond
        ((bolp))
        ((not (string-match "\\S-" (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point))))
         (setq ind (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point))))
        (t (newline))))
     (setq start (point))
     (when (string-match "%file" rpl)
       (setq rpl (replace-match
              (concat
               "\""
               (save-match-data
             (abbreviate-file-name (read-file-name "Include file: ")))
               "\"")
              t t rpl)))
     (setq rpl (mapconcat 'identity (split-string rpl "\n")
                  (concat "\n" ind)))
     (insert rpl)
     (when (re-search-backward "\\?" start t) (delete-char 1))))

     (advice-add 'org-tempo-add-templates :around #'org+-avoid-old-structure-templates)

     (add-hook 'org-tab-after-check-for-cycling-hook #'org-try-structure-completion)

     (require 'org-tempo)
     ))
```